# Is it possible to listen to device connections via libimobiledevice?

Tags: libimobiledevice

I am trying to do something every time my iPhone is connected (via USB or wifi). Current alternative is polling list_devices and wait to see my device listed.
Is there something better or polling is the only option?
This is platform independent, but I am testing on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe for notifications which are sent by iTunes/usbmuxd whenever a new device is connected. If you're using libimobiledevice, you can use [`idevice_event_subscribe`](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/master/include/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.h#L93) to register a callback which is invoked whenever a device is added or removed.